# Create sparse DIA matrix, and then change columns

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two vectors `t`, and `delta` - both of length `n`. I want to create a sparse `DIA` matrix `A` with that vector, and then adjust the columns: For all `i`, I want to move the `ith` entry in `A` by `delta[i]` columns to the left.

An easy way to control columns is in the `COO`  format. Here's what I thought would work:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
A = diags([t], offsets=[-1]).tocoo()
A.col = A.col - delta
```

However, in my example `A.nnz == len(A.col)` is only `216`, while the length of `t` and `delta` is `239`. I don't understand how that happened, given that `nnz` stores ["Number of stored values, including explicit zeros."](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html).

How can I tackle this problem? Here's my example data:

```
from numpy import np
t = np.array([ 2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,
        2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,
        2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.655,  2.155,
        2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,
        2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,
        2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  2.155,  1.655,
        1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,
        1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,
        1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.655,  1.155,
        1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,
        1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,
        1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  1.155,  0.655,
        0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,
        0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,
        0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.655,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,
        0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.405,  0.   ,
        0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,
        0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,
        0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ])
delta = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,
   5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,
   5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5,
   5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,
   5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,
   4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4,
   4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4,
   4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
   4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
   3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2,
   1, 3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 5, 4, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [29]: t = np.array([1.2, 3.2, 4, 0, 0])
In [30]: A = sparse.diags([t], offsets=[-1])
In [31]: A
Out[31]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

The conversion to `coo` strips out the 0s.

```
In [32]: Ac = A.tocoo()
In [33]: Ac
Out[33]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Look at the code for `A.tocoo` (the `dia` to `coo` version).  It has `(self.data != 0)` mask.

---

If I make the `coo` matrix directly it retains the zeros, at least temporarily:

```
In [58]: A.A
Out[58]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  3.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  4. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
In [59]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((t, (np.arange(1,6),np.arange(5))),shape=(6,6))
In [60]: M
Out[60]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [61]: M.A
Out[61]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  3.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  4. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

An inplace zero removal:

```
In [64]: M.eliminate_zeros()
In [65]: M
Out[65]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```